# Sample from a partition uniformly in Python

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'd like to sample from a partition n = 500, k = 12. I know that this is an absurdly large number.

I use `more_itertools.` in order to get the list of partitions.

ex for n=5, k=3

```
>>>>from more_itertools import set_partitions

>>>>list(set_partitions(range(5), 3))
Out[2]: 
[[[0], [1], [2, 3, 4]],
 [[0], [1, 2], [3, 4]],
 [[0], [2], [1, 3, 4]],
 [[0], [1, 2, 3], [4]],
 [[0], [2, 3], [1, 4]],
 [[0], [1, 3], [2, 4]],
 [[0], [3], [1, 2, 4]],
 [[0, 1], [2], [3, 4]],
 [[1], [0, 2], [3, 4]],
 [[1], [2], [0, 3, 4]],
 [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4]],
 [[1], [0, 2, 3], [4]],
 [[1], [2, 3], [0, 4]],
 [[0, 1], [3], [2, 4]],
 [[1], [0, 3], [2, 4]],
 [[1], [3], [0, 2, 4]],
 [[0, 1, 2], [3], [4]],
 [[1, 2], [0, 3], [4]],
 [[1, 2], [3], [0, 4]],
 [[0, 2], [1, 3], [4]],
 [[2], [0, 1, 3], [4]],
 [[2], [1, 3], [0, 4]],
 [[0, 2], [3], [1, 4]],
 [[2], [0, 3], [1, 4]],
 [[2], [3], [0, 1, 4]]]
```

The problem is that for n = 500 and k = 12, this is insanely large! It would still work since it is a generator and thus doesn't store anything in memory, however, the order isn't random.

I was originally thinking of just randomly assigning the 500 elements to 12 sets using the following code -

```
n=500; k=12; ele_arr = list(range(n)); np.random.shuffle(ele_arr);

output = [[] for i in range(k)]
for i, e in enumerate(ele_arr):
    # have to ensure that each partition has at least one element
    if i < k:
        output[i].append(e)
    else:
        j = np.random.randint(0, k-1)
        output[j].append(e)
```

But I not sure it will lead to a uniform random sample of all partitions possible.

Comment: Why do you need them all at once? What is the context?

Comment: Your approach does not sample uniformly because of the initial shuffling. Using n=5 and k=3 {0 1 234} is sampled with probability 1/9 if the shuffle starts with 012 013 or 014 (in any order) but {0 12 34} is sampled with probability 1/9 if the shuffle starts with 013 014 023 or 024 (in any order), which is 33% more likely. For n=500 and k=12 you could just use rejection sampling instead (but that won't work as k gets close to n)

Comment: @Dai - I agree, with small numbers, my approach is wrong. I'm wondering if my approach gets better with bigger numbers.

Comment: It gets worse: take n = 500 and k = 250. Compare partition {{0},{1},...,{248}},{249,250,...,499} with {{0,1},...{498,499}}. First one can be sampled from 249 shuffles while the second can be picked from 2^250 shuffles.